# Acces to object array from all classes

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers, global

first of all, excuse my poor english.

Well, i'm tryng to make a simple game in C++ with Allegro's library, but i don't know how to create an object array wich can be accesed from all clases.

To be more exactly, i have this code in the main() function of the principal class:

```
CBody **objs = new CBody*[n];
objs[0] = new CBall(320,240);
objs[1] = new CRing(500,120);
```

Then i need to make a function in CBall's class to check collision with CRing instance. Something like:

```
bool CBall::CheckRingCol(){
  return (colCircle(myX,myY,myRadious,objs[1]->myX,objs[1]->myY,objs[1]->myRadious));
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks you, guys!

Comment: pass the `CRing` into the `CheckRingCol` method. `bool CBall::CheckRingCol( const CRing& ring )` and call using `obj[0]->CheckRingCol( *obj[1] );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not use double pointer madness. You don't need it.

You have an array of `CBody`, which presumably is a Base class (helps to post more code)

```
#include <memory>
typedef shared_ptr<CBody> spBody;

vector<spBody> bodies;
bodies.emplace_back( spBody(new CBall(320, 140)) ); // don't need to bother about delete when you use a shared_ptr
bodies.emplace_back( spBody(new CRing(500, 120)) );
```

Who calls the ball-ring collision?

You could pass the ring as an argument to `bool CBall::CheckRingCol(const CRing*) const`.

Comment: Thank you very much, excuse me for don't be clearly. Well, ball-ring collision it's called by a instance of CBall.

Comment: No problem. Someone needs to iterate over the CBall's and then call associated CRing's. I'm not sure how this association is made in your code.